# 404 page showing on all pages under middleware

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/Otherpage' component={Otherpage} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
      <Middleware>
          <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
          <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
          <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
      </Middleware>
    </Router>
```

the 404 (NotFound) page is displaying on ALL the pages under my
Middleware, any help please

Comment: I tried that but all pages in under Middleware is showing 404

Comment: Middleware is component that check if a user is logged or not, If not he cant access the Dashboard, if logged it will Redirect to Dashboard. Thanks

Comment: what is `Middleware` and why are the routes outside `Switch`

Comment: Beautiful, so you're trying to do something like `Authentication` based access for those particular routes yh?
I could send you a link on one of my projects for how to implement it

Comment: Yes, Authentication. Thank you, please send the link

Answer (score 0):

Create a wildcard path with an asterisk(‘*’) and add at the very last path of your routes.

Comment: This is not working, and also path="" not working